# On WordPress Dashboard: Change default text for "X Posts" in "Right Now" widget to custom text

Tags: wordpress

I have a customized admin where I have changed posts to "articles" and I changed this text throughout the rest of the site by adding some code to functions.php but can't find a way to alter it in the dashboard widget that, the main default one that is titled "Right Now." I'd like it to say "X Articles" instead of "Posts" here. Anyone know? I'd like to change "X Categories" to a custom taxonomy and eliminate the listings for tags and pages from this space as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the core, I see the string is hardcoded. Two ways to change it: jQuery or the filter [`get_text`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext).

You'll want to load it only in that specific page, so use:

```
add_action( 'load-index.php', 'callback' );
function callback()
{
    // add_filter( 'get_text', etc...
    # OR
    // add_action( 'admin_footer', print jQuery...
}
```

Here's [another example of usage](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/3578).